# D3 Chart Legend Labels getting overlapped

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend, linechart

I have a line chart in my application and it has a legend underneath the chart. The problem is when the number of lines that I'm showing in the line chart is increasing the labels in the legend are getting overlapped with each other. Is there a solution to this problem. Maybe to send the overlapping text to a new line or any sort of solution to this problem?

My sample code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/rzc71jkq/3/

```
    var data = [{
    name: "USA",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Canada",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Maxico",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "India",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Russia",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Japan",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Malaysia",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Korea",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "South Africa",
    values: [{
        date: "2000",
        price: "100"
      },
      {
        date: "2001",
        price: "110"
      },
      {
        date: "2002",
        price: "145"
      },
      {
        date: "2003",
        price: "241"
      },
      {
        date: "2004",
        price: "101"
      },
      {
        date: "2005",
        price: "90"
      },
      {
        date: "2006",
        price: "10"
      },
      {
        date: "2007",
        price: "35"
      },
      {
        date: "2008",
        price: "21"
      },
      {
        date: "2009",
        price: "201"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = 50;
var duration = 250;

var lineOpacity = "0.25";
var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
var lineStroke = "1.5px";
var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

var circleOpacity = '0.85';
var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
var circleRadius = 3;
var circleRadiusHover = 6;


/* Format Data */
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.values.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.price = +d.price;
  });
});


/* Scale */
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width - margin]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.price)])
  .range([height - margin, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width + margin) + "px")
  .attr("height", (height + margin) + "px")
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


/* Add line into SVG */
var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.date))
  .y(d => yScale(d.price));

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');

lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('id',function(d){ return d.name.replace(/\s+/g, '')+"-line"; })
  .attr('class', 'line-group')
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title-text")
      .style("fill", color(i))
      .text(d.name)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", (width - margin) / 2)
      .attr("y", 5);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    svg.select(".title-text").remove();
  })
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
  .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
  .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll('.line')
      .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
    d3.selectAll('.circle')
      .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
      .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
      .style("cursor", "pointer");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".line")
      .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
    d3.selectAll('.circle')
      .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
      .style("cursor", "none");
  });


/* Add circles in the line */
lines.selectAll("circle-group")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr('id',function(d){ return d.name.replace(/\s+/g, '')+"-circle"; })
  .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(d => d.values).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .style("cursor", "pointer")
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "text")
      .text(`${d.price}`)
      .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
      .attr("y", d => yScale(d.price) - 10);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .style("cursor", "none")
      .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .selectAll(".text").remove();
  })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
  .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.price))
  .attr("r", circleRadius)
  .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("r", circleRadius);
  });


/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append('text')
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .text("Total values");


var dataNest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .entries(data);

var legendSpace = width / dataNest.length;

// Loop through each symbol / key
dataNest.forEach(function(d, i) {

  // Add the Legend
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (legendSpace / 2) + i * legendSpace) // space legend
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("class", "legend") // style the legend
    .style("fill", color(i))
    .on("click", function() {
      // Determine if current line is visible
      var active = d.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
      // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
      d3.select("#" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "-line")
        .transition().duration(100)
        .style("opacity", newOpacity);
      d3.select("#" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "-circle")
        .transition().duration(100)
        .style("opacity", newOpacity);
      // Update whether or not the elements are active
      d.active = active;
    })
    .text(d.key);
});
```

Comment: What about a vertical legend right (or left) of the chart?

Comment: can you provide me a sample code for it @Zim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of appending elements in a for loop you should utilize the `.data()` join.

We could map the legend keys like this `data.map(d => d.name)` inside the `data()`.

And instead of appending `text` element to the svg we could append `font` element to the body, this way the text aligns itself without overlapping

Here's all the changes I made:

```
var keys = []

// Add the Legend
var legend = d3.select("body").selectAll(".legend")
    .data(data.map(d => d.name))
.enter().append("font")
    .attr("class", "legend") // style the legend
    .style("color", color)
    .style("margin-left", 10 + "px")
    .style("padding-left", 10 + "px")
    .html(d => d)

d3.selectAll(".legend")
    .on("click", function(d) {

        keys.includes(d) 
            ? keys.splice(keys.indexOf(d), 1)
            : keys.push(d)

        d3.select(this).style("opacity", () => keys.includes(d) ? .5 : 1)

        d3.select("#" + d.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "-line")
            .transition().duration(100)
            .style("opacity", () => keys.includes(d) ? 0 : 1);
        d3.select("#" + d.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "-circle")
            .transition().duration(100)
            .style("opacity", () => keys.includes(d) ? 0 : 1);
    })
```

But as Zim mentioned I'd also put it vertically, but this is more of a design issue rather than code related.

And here's a fork: https://jsfiddle.net/apn8b5my/